# what is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am new to Webservices. when i try to create a webservice I am getting following error.

```
 Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractServiceFactory.createService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.main(JavaToWS.java:45)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:297)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:685)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:536)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractServiceFactory.createService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 20 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "boardingPoint"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.PrintTicket.getBoardingPoint()
        at com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.PrintTicket
        at com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.TicketBooking
        at com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.ServicePassengerBookingInfo
```

I am stuck up with this from past two days.
Here in this scenario, ServicePassengerBookingInfo extends TicketBooking and TicketBooking extends PrintTicket. I have defined a property called boardingPoint in Printticket pojo.

Please let me know how to solve this

endpoint source

```
public class SaveTicketBookingInfo {

    private Long serviceId;
    private Integer adults;
    private Integer childs;
    private String journeyType;
    private Integer journeyTime;
    private Long startPlaceId;
    private Long endPlaceId;
    private Long loginUserId;
    private String paxSeatDetails[];
    private int totalSeatsBooked = 0;
    private Long categoryCodeId[];
    private Long genderCodeId[];
    private String passengerName[];
    private Double passengerAge[];
    private String seatDetails[];
    private Double fareDetails[];
    private Double forwardAdultFare;
    private Double forwardChildFare;
    private double concPerChildPax = 0;
    private int maxPassengerAllowed;
    private String concApplyToChild;
    private int departureDay[];
    private String srvcPlatformNo[];
    private Double concPriceForward;
    private String bookingTypeForward;
    private Double concPriceReturn;
    private String retConc;    
    private String bookingTypeReturn;
    private Long mealIdReturn[];
    private Long mealIdForward[];
    private Double mPriceReturn[];
    private Double mPriceForward[];
    private Integer mQtyForward[];   
    private Integer mQtyReturn[]; 
    private Long depotIds[];
    private Long srvcStationId[];
    private Long accomodationId[];
    private Double tollsPrice[];
    private String acFlag[];   
    private String ticketType;
    private String cancelTicketType;
    private String stockNumber;
    private String stockKey;
    private String cancelType;   
    private String seatNos;
    private int concNoPassengers;
    private String seatsBooked;
    private Long serviceCategoryId;
    private Long concessionId;
    private Double tollFare;
    private String bookingType;
    private String departureTime;
    private String arrivalTime;
    private Double totalAmount;
    private String cardNumber;
    private Double[] bookingTollFare;   
    private Double returnAdultFare;
    private Double returnChildFare;  
    private int retTotalPax = 0;          
    private Double refundPrice;
    private Double refundSrtPrice;
    private Double refundTollFee;
    private Double refundMealPrice;
    private Double refundAccomPrice;
    private Double refundTotalAmount;
    private Long forwardServiceId;
    private Long returnServiceId;
    private Long stationId[];
    private String searchType;
    private String journeyDate;
    private String returnJourneyDate;
    private String[] platFormNo;
    private boolean agentBooking;
    private boolean eBooking;
    private Auditor auditor; 
}
```

with setter and getter methods

Comment: Please post your endpoint's source

Comment: Ouch, a class with 75 fields?  As an aside to the current question, that could *definitely* be refactored to be more reasonable.  For example, add a `Passenger` class with gender, age, etc. and only have a `private List<Passenger>` in your parent class (much like you've done with `Auditor`), instead of `adults`, `child`, `passengerName[]`, `passengerAge[]`, `genderCodeId[]`, etc.

Comment: I have done that doyle, but what about the problem ???

Comment: Do you have a database which consists of little more than a table with 75 columns? If so, your problems start exactly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the *root* cause in the stack trace you've posted:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 20 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "boardingPoint"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.PrintTicket.getBoardingPoint()
```

This is the root cause - implicitly or explicitly, you're defining a class with ambiguous mappings, so that two things map to the same name.  Unsurprisingly this can't be resolved, so the server fails to start up.

Without the full source of the `PrintTicket` class I couldn't say what's causing this, but look at how you're annotating its properties.  It could be that you're exporting both fields *and* methods (so a getter would clash with the field), or you've got two getter methods that match (e.g. `isBoardingPoint` and `getBoardingPoint`), etc.

Comment: hi doyle, i am not having two getter methods. I have set and get methods only in the PrintTicket class. Is this something because of ServicePassengerBookingInfo extends TicketBooking and TicketBooking extends PrintTicket.

Answer (score 0):

I had errors of this type:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 count of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same type name "{...}" . Use @XmlType.name and XmlType.namespace to give them different names.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public com.myapp.package.ClassName
```

Specifying the @XmlType namespace - as suggested in the output - for the class (in above example, ClassName) fixed it for me.